# Rails app with reservations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm making a bed and breakfast app and have been looking through google for three hours trying to figure out how to give a user the ability to reserve a date. I've played around with Date_field and every other example on the rails guide and no luck. I did try the rails guide date_select since I am wanting to query it form the database.

I'm trying to have the user reserve a date and if it is already taken tell the user sorry date is already booked. I don't know how to generate this in a Model.

Would I do rails generate Model Reservation date? and then do

```
<%= form_for @reservation do |f| %>

  <%= f.date_select :date %> 

<% end %>
```

for the form?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
class Reservation < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :date, uniqueness: true
end
```

Will return errors if the date is already taken.

Comment: Ok, sweet... Makes since. So in the Model do I just generate date:integer and is it necessary to add a index to the reservation?

Comment: You'd run a migration to add date to the model if it's not their already, and you want a date field not an integer (or maybe a datetime ) - `rails g migration AddDateToReservations date:date`

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to enable the B & B to `has_many :months`.  For the reservation months, the dates (the relevant number of boolean fields) are loaded into memory and checked whether they are taken (true) or not taken (false).  The check for whether the date is booked can occur within the program, as a conditional.